# C# soap web service and Java client

Tags: c#, java, web-services, soap, wshttpbinding

I have problems with writing Java client for wshttpbinding web service.

I wsimport-ed .wsdl and i try to

```
TestService iface = new TestService();      
ITestService implmt = iface.getWSHttpBindingITestService();
```

then i call web service method  **set**

```
implmt.set("s", 1);
```

And i get

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: 
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

- I cannot change server side, it ***must*** be as is. So change to basicHttpBinding is not possible (if i change it i don't have any problem but alas)
- Client must be made in Java.

Comment: do you have sufficient privileges on this webservice?

Comment: of course. And I can access it with my .net client with no problems.

Comment: Is the client on a Windows box?

Comment: everything is currently on Windows. But there is no guarantee that clients will be on Windows. But, working on multiple platforms is not a must. I would be happy to get an answer that will solve my problems on Windows :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh ok I solved it. I imported METRO .jar files to build path and moved them to top (to be first)

It is crucial to place those jars on top.

[image: java build path]